# UV-Vis absorbtion spectra of a radical cation/anion. Is it different compared to its even counterpart?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, radicals, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I am studying gas-phase Uv-Vis spectra of radical molecules. If one electron is removed/captured from the neutral even electron molecule, what can I expect from the absorption spectra? Will new peaks appear? Will they be blue/red-shifted?

Comment: A cheeky answer is 'yes and yes '. Why not look in the literature for  example spectra, there are bound to be many examples.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a general answer to how the ground state absorption would shift. Here are two publications [1](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00706-019-02404-8), [2](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chemphys.2005.05.009) that observe shifts, but both times a redshift, be it anion or cation. So as of now I dont know how to explain that.

But, I can certainly say that new peaks will apear and they will most likely be in the red part of the spectrum. In the image below you see that the HOMO/LUMO gap is the biggest. Assume now an radical anion, i.e. an additional electron which occupies the LUMO, then transitions to LUMO+i (i=1,2,3,...) are possible which likely have lower energies than the HOMO/LUMO gap.
[image]
Image taken from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234126374_Electron_rectification_through_donor-acceptor-heterocyclics_connected_to_cumulenic_bridge_A_computational_study).